# Como remover a borda de uma janela PyQt5 no RaspBerry Pi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyqt-5

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que irá rodar em um *RaspBerry Pi* com interface em *PyQt5*. Essa aplicação ocupará toda a tela, impossibilitando o usuário clicar fora da aplicação.
Como o monitor sempre será o mesmo, defini uma resolução padrão para as telas, e são exibidas já na posição 0x0 do monitor. No meu *Windows* a aplicação funcionou corretamente, já no *RaspBerry Pi* o comando

```
self.dialog.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

não funciona. Quando deixo essa linha no script a janela nem abre.

- Como posso deixar a minha aplicação sem essa borda?

Uma das formas é de na hora de exibir a tela usar o comando

```
self.window.showFullScreen()
```

mas no caso seria

```
self.dialog.showFullScreen()
```

Mas a questão ainda fica, agora no caso da aplicação que não for fullscreen, e que a pessoa queira implementar a própria barra de menus.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz os testes aqui em um Raspberry Pi e funcionou passando os seguintes parâmetros:

```
self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
```

Lembrando que o comando passa a ser .setWindow**Flags** ao invés de .setWindows**Flag** (uma vez que são mais de um)

Assim, eliminando qualquer borda.